# pandas: how to create new columns based on two columns and aggregate the results

Tags: pandas, aggregation

I am trying to perform a sort of aggregation, but with the creation of new columns.

Let's take the example of the dataframe below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'City':['Los Angeles', 'Denver','Denver','Los Angeles'], 
    'Car Maker': ['Ford','Toyota','Ford','Toyota'],
    'Qty': [50000,100000,80000,70000]})
```

That generates this:

|  | City | Car Maker | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Los Angeles | Ford | 50000 |
| 1 | Denver | Toyota | 100000 |
| 2 | Denver | Ford | 80000 |
| 3 | Los Angeles | Toyota | 70000 |

I would like to have one line per city and the Car Maker as a new column with the Qty related to that City:

|  | City | Car Maker | Ford | Toyota |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Los Angeles | Ford | 50000 | 70000 |
| 1 | Denver | Toyota | 80000 | 100000 |

Any hints on how to achieve that?

I've tried some options with transforming it on a dictionary and compressing on a function, but I am looking for a more pandas' like solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.pivot(index='City', columns='Car Maker', values='Qty').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [dataframe.pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)

```
df.pivot_table(values='Qty', index=['City', 'Car Maker'], columns='Car Maker').reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks, it was almost what I was looking for..
The pivot table generated new columns, but kept the same number of rows. It didn't result in row compression like I had exemplified.